# Generating a sidebar out of sections from a php file

Tags: php

I want to generate a sidebar out of sections (FAQ, CONTACT, etc.) that are defined in a php file. The sections themselves get the id and name from an "anchor" given as an attribute by a shortcode. This works fine. Now I try to get every section existing and run a loop to print it in an li.

```
echo '<!-- Sidebar -->
    <aside>
        <div id="AnchorNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
            <ul class="sideNav">';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( 'wordpress/wp-content/themes/understrap/functions.php' );
$list = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'section' );
echo count( $list ); //Output = 1

foreach ( $list as $i => $item ) {
   echo $list->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
   echo '<li class="current" class="nav-tile" data-toggle = "tooltip" data-
   placement = "left" data-title = "' . $list[ $i ] . '" >
         <a href = "#' . $list[ $i ] . '"> ' . $list[ $i ] . '</a></li>';
}

echo '</ul></div></aside>';
```

Comment: What is your question/problem? Can you describe it?

Comment: Sorry. Yes it does not work. Like the comment says it only counts 1. In my case it should be 4 different sections in total. Also it does not jump in the foreach loop.